# orientationchange() on windows phone browser

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, browser, orientation-changes

is there a way to capture an orientation change event in Windows phone 7 **in the browser**?

in Android and iOS there is the onOrientationchange() event - but in Windows mobile IE9 (Windows phone 7) it just don't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can. You could use some javascript to detect changes to the screen width though to emulate similar behaviour

Comment: thanks! I also found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280579/detecting-orientation-of-windows-phone it basically says what you wrote...

Answer (score 1):

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
    window.onresize = function (event) {
        ...
    }
}

window.onorientationchange = function () {
    ...
}

Comment: This does not work neither. On my Nokia Lumia 710 (WP7.5) there is no rotation. Page is only stretched to width when I rotate it to landscape. (T_T)

Comment: window.onresize = function (event) { window.alert(3);} Confirming event fires on my HTC HD7 when changing orientation. Also fires in HTC HD7 emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `window.resize` event as suggested by @Assaf, and detect the orientation with `window.styleMedia.matchMedium("(orientation: landscape)");`

[matchMedium](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/SafariDOMAdditions/Reference/StyleMedia/StyleMedia/StyleMedia.html), is the non-standard Webkit precursor of HTML5 [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) [supported in IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).