# window.orientation returns different values in iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, orientation

I am testing my Web Application on **iPad** *(Safari browser)* and **Samsung Tab 2** *(Default browser)*. The *window.orientationchange* returns different values in both the devices.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            window.addEventListener("orientationchange", centerLoginBox);
            window.addEventListener("load", centerLoginBox);
        });

        function centerLoginBox() {
            if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) { //Landscape Mode
                $('#loginbox').css('margin-top', '20%');
                alert(window.orientation);
            }
            else if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) { //Portrait Mode
                $('#loginbox').css('margin-top', '40%');
                alert(window.orientation);
            }
```

In Tab 2 the alert throws '0' and '180' for *landscape* mode and the values '90' and '-90' for *portrait* mode(**just the opposite behavior in iPad**).

Is this some kind of design difference in iOS and Android? What could be a common solution for this issue?

Comment: In my testing iPad, iPhone and Nexus 4 all return the same values: 0 for normal portrait, 90 for anticlockwise landscape, -90 for clockwise landscape and 180 for upside down portrait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did. I queried for the User Agent information and checked if the device was Android based. If so, change the conditions of *window.orientation* for both Portrait and Landscape mode.

**CODE**

```
function centerLoginBox() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; // Detect Android devices
        if (isAndroid) {
            //window.orientation is different for iOS and Android
            if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) { //Landscape Mode
                $('#loginbox').css('margin-top', '20%');
            }
            else if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) { //Portrait Mode
                $('#loginbox').css('margin-top', '40%');
            }
        }
        else {
            if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) { //Landscape Mode
                $('#loginbox').css('margin-top', '20%');
            }
            else if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) { //Portrait Mode
                $('#loginbox').css('margin-top', '40%');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: well, it seems now both will be in landscape mode when o=90||-90

Comment: I agree, latest tests I made have shown now iOS and Android are working the same way for window.orientation

Comment: does `window.orientation` still return a different value for android??

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the second answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript) question you can assign two listeners: one for the orientation change and one for the resize of the screen width/height values. this way you dont have to rely on the values of the rotation because they are inconsistent in different devices.

Comment: But the _window.orientation_ values will still differ........and the problem remains the same.

Comment: [This](https://notes.matthewgifford.com/a-misconception-about-window-orientation-7231235a94c2) explains some of the details of _window.orientation_ values on different devices.