# enhance javascript code for screen orientation

Tags: javascript

Having tried a load of different options found on SO, including jQuery mobile solutions (caused masses of conflicts with other jQuery) i found the following code would detect screen rotation and i could use it to add a class.

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
screenOrientation = ($(window).height() > $(window).width())? 90 : 0;
$('.centerBoxContentsSubCat').addClass('mobile_landscape');
});
```

However, I need to .removeClass when rotated the other way.

I tried duplicating the code, switching the positions of height and width, but this didn't work.
I tried changing the code to

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
if(screenOrientation = ($(window).height() > $(window).width())? 90 : 0){
$('.centerBoxContentsSubCat').addClass('mobile_landscape');
}else{
$('.centerBoxContentsSubCat').removeClass('mobile_landscape');
}
});
```

but that didn't work either.

I am actually using @media queries for css, but i need to force a change in a column count on screen rotate and all other attempts have failed to get even close.

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different ways you can handle this.

The first is with the event orientation change.

```
// Listen for orientation changes
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    // Announce the new orientation number
    alert(window.orientation);
}, false);
```

The second is with matchMedia.

```
// Find matches
var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

// If there are matches, we're in portrait
if(mql.matches) {  
    // Portrait orientation
} else {  
    // Landscape orientation
}

// Add a media query change listener
mql.addListener(function(m) {
    if(m.matches) {
        // Changed to portrait
    }
    else {
        // Changed to landscape
    }
});
```

Source:
http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change

If you need to support older browsers I recommend this library:

https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/

Comment: Whilst your answer is valid, it does have a shortcoming, which is why I looked for something else. Where you show a comment of Portrait I added $('.centerBoxContentsSubCat').removeClass('mobile_landscape'); , and where it shows a landscape comment I added $('.centerBoxContentsSubCat').addClass('mobile_landscape');
The problem i found was that if the page was loaded with the device already in landscape view it did not add the class. Switching to portrait and back would trigger the addClass.

Comment: Try it with the media queries. I've done something here that might work: https://github.com/michaelBenin/node-startup/blob/develop/browser/js/mixins/device_manager.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `orientationchange` event, not resize.

Comment: I tried countless examples of this from StackOverflow and other sites and could not get it to switch correctly.
This is one such example I tried, and also points out some short comings with orientationchange. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019939/window-orientation-returns-different-values-in-ios-and-android
Given that it is a basic feature of all smartphones, the fact it is so complicated to get a workable solution cross platform is ridiculous.